# How to set the authorization header value?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I want to set the `authorization` header and set its value to `Bearer Token` with the value `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIs`. How can I do that? This is my AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "/organisation/list",
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      alert(""+data);
    }
  });
});
```

In the list route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
  var request = require("request");
  var url = "https://api.tag-ip.com/track/organizations";
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where do you want to put authorisation header? Frontend or backend?

Comment: it does not matter if it works :)

Comment: @mjakic very odd question considering it has to go in the front end when it sends the request...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe tag-ip service needs authorisation.

Comment: Given the OPs logic a remote error would get swallowed and not reported back to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings object you provide to `$.ajax()` has a `headers` property which you can provide an object containing the headers to be set. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/organisation/list",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIs'
    }
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

There's a couple of other things to note here. Firstly, don't use `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice. You're already using the `success` callback so there's no need for it anyway. Secondly, don't use `alert()` for debugging. `console.log()` is better as it's not modal, and it does not coerce data types. To view its output open the browser developer tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I get a `response.statusCode` of 400 within the route ! how to deal with the header sent from the client side in the router ?

Comment: That's a separate issue. A 400 error means there is something wrong with the data youre sending in the request